# PHP Convert html to pdf OR Convert html to image

Tags: php, html, imagecreatefrompng

Please provide me suggesion to convert html tp image 
or convert html to pdf  in `PHP` 
If any code u have then please let me know.....thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to take a look at [HTML2PDF](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default).

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. Ask Google, then come back here with specific implementation problems once you've actually tried something. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

For PDF conversion, it will help you. This will convert the HTML page to PDF page

**[HTML to PDF Converter](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)**

Answer (score -1):

For converting html to pdf using PHP, try [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)

[TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) is a FLOSS PHP class for generating PDF documents.

DEMOs: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php